# npm libraries gives Error when Installing

Tags: android, node.js, npm, react-native, npm-install

when I try to install any library from npm it gives me this error

```
 355 error Windows_NT 10.0.10240
    356 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" 
    "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "react-native-qrcode-view" "--save"
    357 error node v6.2.1
    358 error npm  v3.9.3
    359 error code ENOGIT
    360 error not found: git
    361 error Failed using git.
    361 error This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
    361 error Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.
```

Please help I try to update the node.js but I still have this Error

Comment: According to the message, `360 error not found: git`, you do not have `git` installed.

Comment: if you DO have git installed, is it accessible in the %path% that the current npm job is running?

Comment: which path shall I install git on it is it `"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"` ?

Comment: you might want to learn more about what the %path% is before proceeding... http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: @ptierno Sorry for being dummy :( , but the default path is `C:\\Program Files` and I install the git on the same directory

Comment: that is not the `path`